# How can I determine which network adapter a device is using for packet emission when attempting to reach a specific IP address using ping?

Tags: ip, ping, windows-command-prompt, host

I have been trying to reach a particular IP and I have not been able to check on which Network Adapter it is using for publishing. Is there any way to check on a particular device to verify whether it is being used for packets emmission?

I tried on the different options given by ping on *cmd* but I have not been yet able to check on the proper equipment. I have added the associated IP that I want to check and performed an *ipconfig* but I haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `route print` will show the information you are looking for (on MS-Windows, the interface is indicated by its IP address)

Comment: thank you very much @symcbean. Could you provide please an example for me to understand it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

From a command prompt, type `route print`.  You will see something similar to this:

```
H:\>route print

<...>    
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        0.0.0.0            0.0.0.0      172.19.2.3       172.19.2.20     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
       172.19.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       172.19.2.20    281
      172.19.2.20  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.19.2.20    281
     172.19.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.19.2.20    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.19.2.20    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       172.19.2.20    281
===========================================================================
```

Use the columns `Network Destination` and `Netmask` to determine the best match to the destination (longest mask is the best).  Note the `Interface address`.  That is the address of the outgoing interface.

Most likely, you will be using the destination 0.0.0.0 (default route).